# How to create sencha packages for phone and tablet?

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I have created a sencha app using sencha 2.3 and i created a .xap file of the same. When i open it in the Windows Phone 8, i get only white screen. Also i want to create a package for windows tablet and for ipad of the same app. Please provide me the necessary steps for creating the packages. I'm completely new to sencha, any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Selva

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you a lot: http://phonegap.com/blog/2013/11/20/SenchaPhoneGap/